# Play two Videos at same time

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have an app that shows a dancing toy in a VideoView at full screen. Sometimes another video executes over the video of the toy, in this case i have problems with the view because the video of the top shows transparent.

If i set vid1.stopPlayback(); before call the second video, it works, but i cant reproduce the first.

Is there some way to play both videos at same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not fully certain, but I got a feeling I've read simultaneous video playback may not be possible due to the way it is rendered on the screen. I can't find where I read about this, but you may try searching that way though.

Comment: I couldn't find anything in google or here too... but i had the faith that someone knows how to do that. Anyway, thanks!